# RAIDs with a lot of spindles - how to safely put to use the "wasted" space

Tags: storage, best-practices

I have a fairly large number of RAID arrays (server controllers as well as midrange SAN storage) that all suffer from the same problem: barely enough spindles to keep the peak I/O performance, and tons of unused disk space.

I guess it's a universal issue since vendors offer the smallest drives of 300 GB capacity but the random I/O performance hasn't really grown much since the time when the smallest drives were 36 GB.

One example is a database that has 300 GB and needs random performance of 3200 IOPS, so it gets 16 disks (4800 GB minus 300 GB and we have 4.5 TB wasted space).

Another common example are redo logs for a OLTP database that is sensitive in terms of response time. The redo logs get their own 300 GB mirror, but take 30 GB: 270 GB wasted.

What I would like to see is a systematic approach for both Linux and Windows environment. How to set up the space so sysadmin team would be reminded about the risk of hindering the performance of the main db/app? Or, even better, to be protected from that risk? The typical situation that comes to my mind is "oh, I have this very large zip file, where do I uncompress it? Umm let's see the `df -h` and we figure something out in no time..." I don't put emphasis on strictness of the security (sysadmins are trusted to act in good faith), but on overall simplicity of the approach.

For Linux, it would be great to have a filesystem customized to cap I/O rate to a very low level - is this possible?

Comment: "since vendors offer the smallest drives of 300 GB"? What planet? Last time I checked 75gb SAS drives were still available. "redo logs for a OLTP database that is sensitive in terms of response time" - ever heard of caching? Get a good raid controller. Really. You would be surprised.

Comment: Well, today, big vendors are pretty much using 300GB as the smallest SAS 2.5" disk option. When I send my failed 146GB HP disks in for warranty, I receive 300GB drives labeled as 146GB.

Comment: 75Gb SAS? What planet? When I worked at Dell, we didn't carry those already. And that was 2007.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look into moving the high IOPS/low space req databases to SSD based arrays - those disks are small and provide excellent throughput. This is as simple an approach as it will ever get

Comment: Accepting after two years. Although it isn't literally an answer to my question, it answers the spirit of it :)

Answer (score 3):

[LUNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_unit_number), [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) and selective presentation of resources...

Just because a SAN is backed by 16 disk spindles doesn't mean that the server consuming that data needs to see the full capacity of the array. Same thing with direct-attached storage. There are times where I may have a large number of disks in an array, but I'll still right-size the LUN/partition/device presented to the operating system.

The example below from an HP ProLiant SmartArray controller shows 4 x 480GB SSDs in a RAID 1+0 array. That's 960GB usable. I carved a 400GB LUN out of that 960GB. The operating system only sees 400GB. And even that 400GB is partitioned into logical chunks that make sense for the application. The point is that you can control what the consumers of the storage space see:

```
   array B (Solid State SATA, Unused Space: 1012121  MB)


      logicaldrive 3 (400.0 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, Solid State SATA, 480.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, Solid State SATA, 480.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:7 (port 2I:box 1:bay 7, Solid State SATA, 480.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:1:8 (port 2I:box 1:bay 8, Solid State SATA, 480.1 GB, OK)
```

But in the end, if the performance meets your needs and the organization can afford the current configuration, why do you deem unused space as "wasted"?

BTW - It *is* possible to throttle I/O in Linux on a block-device level [using cgroups](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch-Subsystems_and_Tunable_Parameters.html#blkio-throttling). But if there's a risk to your main applications or databases, why not separate the workloads?

Comment: I think I'm understanding your answer and if so, then I agree. Build your storage array to meet your I/O needs and provision appropriately sized chunks of it to the systems that need those chunks.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yep. Don't leave allocated space out there if it's not needed.

Comment: @ewwhite cgroups have blkio.write_iops_device but it "does not work for buffered write operations. It is primarily targeted at direct I/O."